# Default session time out in Apache and CentOS

Tags: php, apache, centos

Anyone can help me to find out the default session time out in apache and CentOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from php in `php.ini` and not apache or the OS.

The default value is 1440 (measured in seconds, so 24 minutes) but it depends on your hosting provider. The specific setting you are looking for is

`session.gc_maxlifetime`

EDIT:

Things to which the `Timeout` directive mentioned in the other answers applies:

1. When reading data from the client, the length of time to wait for a TCP packet to arrive if the read buffer is empty.
2. When writing data to the client, the length of time to wait for an acknowledgement of a packet if the send buffer is full.
3. In mod_cgi, the length of time to wait for output from a CGI script.
4. In mod_ext_filter, the length of time to wait for output from a filtering process.
5. In mod_proxy, the default timeout value if ProxyTimeout is not configured.

source on edit: [Apache HTTP Server core docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout)