# How to get user logout when he close browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, security, session

I have a website with login system after user and password are correct update user set flag 1 to not allow other people to connect with that user at same time

```
$sql="update user set flag = 1 where id_user =".$_SESSION['id_user'];
```

i have a logout.php who reset flag to 0 when i click logout button,but i also  want to changed flag to 0 when user close browser.

I tried to sloved it with :
javascript/jquery onbeforeunload unload and 
Sessions destory but i failed

Comment: This is not a good idea. What happens if their browser crashes? You've now locked them out indefinitely.

Comment: I have at login.php a link to reset flag

Comment: to add more scenarios to what @Darkrum said there is when the power is cut, computer crash, network dropout. also depending on what this reset flag link does it would only provide an unnecessary step for some users which wont be of any benefit since a second person can then reset the flag with this link while the first person is still actively logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it this way.

Upon logon, you should check your session store whether there is a session for the user requesting logon. This of course needs a session store that you can actually check, ie. in a database.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion to solve with PHP, forgetting JavaScript

Stores the last request time from the logged user in your database, maybe in a field of the user table and in a cookie also (client side). So, every time the user make a request, update this field on the user table to the current time and the cookie also.

If anybody try to connect with a user that have `flag = 1`, verify the last request time. If it was five (or ten, or twenty, or whatever) minutes ago or more, allow log in. If it was less than this time, just not allow.

If allowed, then we have two person with a session in the system, so the two are logged, it is a problem.

To solve this, when anyone of them try to view the page, if the last request time stored in cookie (client side) is different from the stored in database, so destroy session. If is equal, the navigation is allowed and the last request time is update again (in the cookie and database).

The idea is that five (or ten, or twenty, or whatever) minutes of inactivity means that the user leaves.

You can also change `session.gc_maxlifetime` in `php.ini` to a lower time. For example, to five minutes, try:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime=300
```

After change `php.ini`, restart Apache.

See [Default session time out in Apache and CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066913/default-session-time-out-in-apache-and-centos)

Answer (score 0):

it's bad idea to do this. if you want to check user login, you need more parameter instead of just flag the user login or not. i agree with @Helinton Mello , you can check by the time the user last login if the user login 10 minutes ago the flag is still 1 you can give him access to login but if the user is under 10 minutes, you can give another notification like "you allready login, please contact your administrations network".