# How to increase Auth session expire time in Cakephp 3.x?

Tags: php, session, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to keep Auth session expire time increase till close the browser,

I have followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694932/how-to-increase-cakephp-auth-component-session-expire-time), and update the session expire time At `config/app.php` with,

`'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout'=>24*60//in minutes
],`

But, the same issue occurs, auth session timeout/expire without a closing browser.

Comment: Check your session cookies expiration date, it may expire before the session on the server times out. Also make sure that `ini_set()` is allowed, as CakePHP needs to modify the `session.gc_maxlifetime` value.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no easy implementation (if at all) to close the PHP session when the browser closes.  A day should be plenty for any normal user.

Comment: I have increase `timeout` variable to `24*60` means 1 Day, but the issue is that .. auth session expired in 1 hr...

Comment: ah ok. Perhaps cakephp is not able to override your servers default session time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066913/default-session-time-out-in-apache-and-centos